# Flux actions for UI events

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am using react and flux in my application, In my application I have two components: TreeView and TableView and their is fetched from two different stores.

I want to add an option - when I click on a row in my TableView it will open the relevant node in my TreeView.

My question is: How those two components should talk to each other? In AngularJS/Backbone I will use an Event Aggreator pattern and will broadcast an event like - "objectSelected" with it's id.

How should I do this in react with flux architecture - I thought using the flux way - and creating an action, but then my store will save UI state (which nodes are open) and I think that the component (in this case TreeView) should save this state (and not the store).

So what's the correct for talking between two components in react?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use flux, then you would pass actions as props through a parent component.

The only flux implementation I've used is Fluxxor. Using fluxxor (and probably most flux implementations) you can have both a component state and a store state. If your table and tree are always going to be linked (both open or closed at the same time), I think it would be okay to save it in a store.

You might do something like ..

```
TableComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      //component specific state
    };
  },

  getStateFromFlux: function() {
    // flux store state
    return {
      appStore: this.getFlux().store('AppStore').state
    }
  },

  handleClick: function(tree) {
    this.getFlux().actions.appActions.toggleTree(tree);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Jon, is this OK design-wise to save ui state in the stores?

Comment: When at all possible I try to avoid saving component state in a store. In this case, I think it would be okay to have a specific store that saves open/close state if different components are both relying on it. If it makes you uncomfortable, then add a parent component that will handle the open/close state for both the children :)

Comment: And how will the children component talk to the parent? using a public function on the parent? and the parent will change the props and it will propogate to the children?